# Pipenv: Specify version of setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, pipenv

I'm running into an error with `setuptools` that is supposedly fixed in version `31.0.0`.  I'm using `pipenv` as a virtual environment manager, so I have both a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`.

I've specified:

```
setuptools = "==31.0.0"
```

in my `Pipfile`

I run `pipenv install` but don't see anything show up in my `Pipfile.lock`.  However, if I run:

`pipenv run
import setuptools
setuptools.__version__`

I get back:

`40.0.0`

Any idea how I can specify `31.0.0` and why my current approach is incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason for not doing `pipenv install setuptools==31.0.0` directly? If I do it and then `pipenv run python -c "import setuptools;print(setuptools.__version__)"` I get `31.0.0`

Comment: @DeepSpace So that seems to work but isn't reflected in the `Pipfile.lock` which makes me think it's not being used when I make use of the lock file later